# Reverse function to tolerance interval, using R

Tags: r, tolerance-interval

Given a data set and a min/max range, I want to know (with given alpha value) what portion of the population will be in it. This is the opposite of the tolerance interval, as I see it.

Comment: How is the range related to the data?  Was it stipulated independently of the data collection or has it been derived from the data themselves?

Comment: It's not derived from the data, it's related to real-life limitations which are not related to it.